Does numerical trivial divisor on generic fiber extends to relative numerical trivial divisor?
Let $X, Z$ be complex smooth projective varieties, $f: X\rightarrow Z$ a contraction, and $U\subset Z$ an open subset. Suppose there exists a divisor $L_U$ on $X_U$ such that
$$L_U\equiv _U 0,$$
does there exist a divisor $L$ on $X$ such that $L\equiv_Z 0$ and $L|_{X_U}=L_U$?

What does $\equiv_U$ mean?

It means for every projective curve $C$ on $X_U$ if it maps to a point on $U$, then the intersect number $C.L_U=0$.
